# Detect Android Back button press in android.view.View

Tags: android, onkeydown, onbackpressed

How can I detect Android Back button press in `android.view.View`, during custom View creation (not in **Activity** by overriding `onBackPressed`)?

Comment: Something like `view.setOnKeyListener`?

Comment: `view.setOnKeyListener` not work .....

Comment: Navigation events are a controller/presenter responsibility, not a view responsibility. So, have the activity call some method on your custom `View` from its `onBackPressed()` method.